# Export filtered result from Google Drive Table

Tags: database, google-drive-api, export, google-app-maker

From my understanding, data can’t be access if we are using **Google Drive Table** as the back-end and the only way to see the data is through the **table** widget or export the data to a **spreadsheet**.

I manage to export the data to Google spreadsheet but the problem is I just want to export the data on a specific **date**. I manage to do filtering on the table showing data on a specific date, but I can’t export the data according to that specific date. Instead the whole data will be exported.

Is there a way we can ***export data to a spreadsheet from the table that had been filtered by date?***. Really appreciate if anyone could solve this.

Comment: Short answer is, yes it is possible. However, it involves a lot of scripting depending on how many filters you can apply on your datasource. Then you have to add parameters to your datasource and set those parameters equal to your filters via a client script. From your client script you pass those parameters to a server script and set your filters on the server script again to filter your model and then you can create a spreadsheet using SpreadsheetApp service. If I have time I might throw something quick together.

Comment: woah sound very complicated to a beginner like me though, yes can you please share me the how you will do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the spreadsheet file is in Google Drive API, yes, you can export it using [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it). This is mentioned in:

[How you can export data](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#how_you_can_export_data)

To export data you must have:

- **Access to the App Maker app**—You must either be the author of the app or it must be shared with you (with Can edit or Can view access).
- **Access to the deployment**—You must have published the deployment.
- **Access to the Sheet**—You own the Sheet, because App Maker creates it in your Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I already succeed in exporting the data it just that I can't export data according to the filtering that I have made from the table because I only need to export data according to a specific date.

Comment: Try to move move all the filtered data to a different sheet and export that sheet.

Comment: how can I do that?